# Tag error when PyParsing using setResultsName() and asXML()

Tags: xml, pyparsing

I want to use PyParsing to parse text and output as XML (`asXML()`). But the tags in XML output is inconsistent with `setResultsName`.

Please see the following code segments:

```
p1 = (Literal('a').setResultsName('tag_a')).setResultsName('tag_out')
print(p1.parseString('a').asXML())
# Output:
# <tag_out>
#   <tag_out>a</tag_out>
# </tag_out>

p2 = (Literal('a').setResultsName('tag_a') +
      Literal('b').setResultsName('tag_b')).setResultsName('tag_out')
print((p2.parseString('a b').asXML()))

# The result is randomly chosen from these two outputs.
# <tag_out>
#   <tag_a>a</tag_a>
#   <tag_b>b</tag_b>
# </tag_out>
#
# <tag_out>
#   <tag_out>a</tag_out>
#   <tag_b>b</tag_b>
# </tag_out>
```

Note that the tag of first inner element is often wrong.

Is this a known bug of PyParsing?
What are the patch/workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pyparsing does not automatically impart structure to the expressions in your grammar based on your code. This is by design, so that partial expressions can be easily merged together, so that:

```
grammar = exprA + exprB + exprC
```

and

```
grammar = exprA + (exprB + exprC)
```

and

```
tmp = exprA + exprB
grammar = tmp + exprC
```

behave the same way.  So just putting ()'s around an expression does not automatically define another level of your grammar.

Pyparsing provides the `Group` class for what you want.  Your results will improve greatly if you change your code to:

```
p1 = Group(Literal('a').setResultsName('tag_a')).setResultsName('tag_out')
print(p1.parseString('a').asXML())

p2 = Group(Literal('a').setResultsName('tag_a') +
      Literal('b').setResultsName('tag_b')).setResultsName('tag_out')
print((p2.parseString('a b').asXML()))
```

That being said, `asXML()` is not the greatest part of pyparsing, as it has to make guesses under certain circumstances when walking a structure and creating the output tags. If this is just for debugging purposes, I recommend using the `dump()` method instead.

I also recommend that you switch to the implicit callable form of `setResultsName` -  I think it streamlines your grammar code without hurting readability. See the difference:

```
p1 = Group(Literal('a')('tag_a'))('tag_out')
print(p1.parseString('a').asXML())

p2 = Group(Literal('a')('tag_a') + Literal('b')('tag_b'))('tag_out')
print((p2.parseString('a b').asXML()))
```

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate explanations. One follow-up question is why your `p1` gives two level of `tag_out`: `<tag_out><tag_out> <tag_a>a</tag_a> </tag_out> </tag_out>`. I guess inner one is for `Group()`, but what is the outer one for?
As for `setResultsName`, I think explicit function call helps when I come back after months :)